# How to pass one_hot encoding labels into flow_from_dataframe?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am using `flow_from_dataframe` to pass in my images to the generator. However I worked using cifar10 data. In the flow from dataframe method there is a parameter `"y_col"` that needs to be set which contains the column for the labels. I am having my file as the following.

```
           Name  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14 
00001522_000.png 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0
00023313_000.png 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0
00023313_001.png 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0
00023313_002.png 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0    0    1    0    0    0
```

If we look at it the last image falls into multiple classes.

Now the file with which I learnt the method, the file looks like the following:

```
id,label
 1,frog
 2,truck
 3,truck
 4,deer
```

Below is the code I have used

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r".\train.csv")

datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df,directory=".\train_imgs", x_col="id", y_col="label", has_ext=False, class_mode="categorical", target_size=(32,32), batch_size=32)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
             input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001,loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                validation_data=valid_generator,
                validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                epochs=10)
```

How can I arrange my label columns so that there can be a single column for the `"y_col"` parameter just like the second file. Or is there any other of of without changing the labels I can pass it into the `y_col`?